# Better way than using a var outside a func to track device orientation?

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables, orientation

*Note: The non-specific solution being sought here is how to avoid triggering code if the screen size hasn't changed, e.g. flipping an iPad on its Y-axis (from landscapeLeft to landscapeRight) to show a view to someone without it resizing. In other words, the view will rotate without resizing anything). The test essentially verifies that no intermediate rotation to a different orientation occurred.*

I'm working on a mapping app and want to keep to zoom level constant when switching between orientations. However, a bug of sorts crept in when portrait upsidedown isn't supported, which is the way I want to go with phones, but not with iPads (where there is no problem whatsoever).

When I rotate the device between portrait and landscape and back, there's no issue. But rotating from either landscape mode to portrait upsidedown doesn't trigger viewWillTransition. Consequently, rotating from there to the opposite landscape mode (eg. landscapeLeft > portraitUpsideDown > landscapeRight) triggers a call to viewWillTransition and multiplies the map's current height by the aspectRatio again, resulting in zooming out.

To stop this, I created a global var outside the func and set it to retain the previous orientation. This code works fine. But if there's a better way than using a global var I'd like to learn.

```
var previousOrientation = ""

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    var newOrientation = "";

    switch UIDevice.current.orientation{
    case .portrait:
        newOrientation="Portrait"

    case .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight:
        newOrientation="Landscape"

    default:
        newOrientation="Portrait"
    }

    if newOrientation == previousOrientation {return}
    else{ previousOrientation = newOrientation}

    let bounds = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds // alway related to portrait mode
    let screenWidth = bounds.width
    let screenHeight = bounds.height

    let aspectRatio = Float(screenHeight/screenWidth)

    if(UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait){

        mapViewC.height = mapViewC.height / aspectRatio
    }
    else{

        mapViewC.height = mapViewC.height * aspectRatio
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considerable research and testing, I found that the most reliable way to do this (AFAIK) was to keep the global var but to use the CGSize that is being passed as a means of testing. It's immediately available whereas orientation might not yet be set. Quickly rotating or flipping the device would cause errors with the latter. I was not able to trigger an error when using size as shown here:

```
var previousSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    if size == previousSize {return}
    else{ previousSize = size}

    let aspectRatio = Float(size.height/size.width)

    mapViewC.height = mapViewC.height / aspectRatio
}
```

Comment: I was encountering an issue when testing my app on an iPad. For some reason, the orientation I got in `viewWillTransition` was different when I ran it on iPhone. Seems like it gives you the previous orientation on iPhone, but on iPad it gives you the orientation it is transitioning to. Keeping track of the previous orientation as a global variable is a good way to go!